# How to link jsPlumb

Tags: html, jsplumb

I'm having trouble trying to use the jsPlumb library. I've tried using this among other things at the top of my html file. Could someone please possibly post a js fiddle or give me a working link to the library? Thanks,

Jackson

```
    <script data-require="jsplumb@*" data-semver="1.7.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/1.4.1/jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.1-all-min.js
```

Comment: That link is fine. Your script tag is not closed here. Make sure to import the dependencies and initialize the jsplumb object. [Detailed here](http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/home.html#setup)

Comment: sure. i'll do that in  a second.

Comment: okay guys. The javascript is currently empty. My goal is this. To have a line connecting the two divs shown, using js plumb. could someone please show me how to do this, preferably using a js fiddle. Thank you !
https://jsfiddle.net/gauss123/rxmzbsbq/

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include jQuery:

`<!-- Include jsPlumb -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
        <script data-require="jsplumb@*" data-semver="1.7.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/1.4.1/jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.1-all-min.js</script>`

An alternative would be to download jsPlumb from github ([here](https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/tree/master/dist/js))
and then place that in your websites folder and include the script like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.jsPlumb-1.7.5-min.js"></script>
```